# Ошибка в коде

Tags: php

Доступа к хостингу нет.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/a12997/public_html/shaanxi86.ru/templates/mega_extramy/index.php on line 72
```

Вот код блока:

```
<?php
//No direct access!
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;
include_once(JPATH_ROOT . "/templates/" . $this->template . '/lib/splitmodules.php');
JHTML::_('behavior.framework', true);
$doc = &JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScript(JURI::root().'/templates/'.$this->template.'/js/mega.script.js');
if($this->countModules('menu')){
  $doc->addScript(JURI::root().'/templates/'.$this->template.'/js/mega_menudropdown.js');
}
?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" dir="<?php echo $this->direction; ?>" >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

<?php
  $menu =& JSite::getMenu();
  if($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()){
    $home = true;
  }else{
    $home = false;
  }
?>
<jdoc:include type="head" />
  <link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/css/template.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/css/typography.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/css/customs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/css/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!--[if IE 6]>
  <link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template?>/css/ie6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 7]>
  <link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template?>/css/ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 8]>
  <link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template?>/css/ie8.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->

<?php if($this->countModules('right')) {
  $fright = '';
}else{
  $fright = '_fr';
}
?>
<?php if($this->countModules('left')) {
  $fleft = '';
}else{
  $fleft = '_fl';
}
?>
</head>
<body id="page">
  <div class="mega_wrapper">
    <div class="mega_wrapper_i">
      <div class="mega_header">
        <div class="mega_header_i">
          <div class="logo_follow_slide">
            <div class="logo_follow_slide_i">
              <div class="logobox">
                <div class="logobox_r">
                  <div class="logobox_l">
                    <div class="logobox_p">
                      <jdoc:include type="modules" name="logo" />
                      <?php } ?>
                      <?php if(!$this->countModules('logo')) { ?>
                      <a href="<?php echo JURI::base()?>"  class="logo"></a>
                      <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                  </div>  
                </div>  
              </div>
              <?php if($this->countModules('login + follow')) {?>
              <div class="mega_login_follow">
                <div class="mega_login_follow_i">
                  <?php if($this->countModules('follow')) {?>
                  <div class="mega_follow">
                    <div class="follow_i">
                      <jdoc:include type="modules" name="follow" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <?php } ?>
                  <?php if($this->countModules('login')) {?>
                  <div class="mega_login">
                    <div class="mega_login_i">
                      <jdoc:include type="modules" name="login" />
                    </div>  
                  </div>
                  <?php }?>
                </div>
              </div>
              <?php }?>
              <?php if($this->countModules('slide')) {?>
              <div class="mega_slide">
                <div class="slide_i">
                  <jdoc:include type="modules" name="slide" />
                </div>  
              </div>
              <?php }?>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>  
      </div>
      <?php if($this->countModules('menu + search')) {?>
      <div class="menu_search">
        <?php if($this->countModules('menu')) {?>
        <div class="mega_menu">
          <div class="mainmenu_left"></div>
            <div class="mainmenu_mid">
              <div id="mega_menu">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="menu" />
              </div>
            </div>  
          <div class="mainmenu_right"></div>  
        </div>
        <?php }?>
        <?php if($this->countModules('search')) {?>
        <div class="mega_search">
          <div class="search_i">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="search" />
          </div>  
        </div>
        <?php }?>
      </div>
      <?php }?>  
      <div class="mega_main_body">
        <div class="mega_main_body_i">
          <?php if($this->countModules('breadcrumb')) {?>
          <div class="mega_breadcrumb">
            <div class="mega_breadcrumb_i">
              <jdoc:include type="modules" name="breadcrumb" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <?php }?>
          <!-- TOP MODULES START HERE -->
                  <?php
                  $template = array ('topbox-1','topbox-2','topbox-3','topbox-4');
                  $tops = splitmodules ($this,$template,99);
                  if($tops) :
                  ?>
                  <?php if($this->countModules('topbox-1 + topbox-2 + topbox-3 + topbox-4')) {?>
                  <div class="mega_tops" id="mega_tops">
                      <div class="mega_tops_i" id="mega_tops_i">
                        <?php if( $this->countModules('topbox-1')) {?>
                        <div class="topbox topbox1<?php echo $tops['topbox-1']['class']; ?>" style="width: <?php echo $tops['topbox-1']['width']; ?>;">
                              <jdoc:include type="modules" name="topbox-1" style="megabox" />
                        </div>
                        <?php }?>
                        <?php if( $this->countModules('topbox-2')) {?>
                        <div class="topbox topbox2<?php echo $tops['topbox-2']['class']; ?>" style="width: <?php echo $tops['topbox-2']['width']; ?>;">
                              <jdoc:include type="modules" name="topbox-2" style="megabox" />
                        </div>
                        <?php }?>
                        <?php if( $this->countModules('topbox-3')) {?>
                        <div class="topbox topbox3<?php echo $tops['topbox-3']['class']; ?>" style="width: <?php echo $tops['topbox-3']['width']; ?>;">
                              <jdoc:include type="modules" name="topbox-3" style="megabox" />
                        </div>
                        <?php }?>
                         <?php if( $this->countModules('topbox-4')) {?>
                        <div class="topbox topbox4<?php echo $tops['topbox-4']['class']; ?>" style="width: <?php echo $tops['topbox-4']['width']; ?>;">
                              <jdoc:include type="modules" name="topbox-4" style="megabox" />
                        </div>
                        <?php }?>
                      </div> 
                  </div>
                  <?php } endif;?>
                  <!-- END -->
                  <div class="main_content">
                    <div class="main_content_i">
                      <div class="message">
                <jdoc:include type="message" />
              </div>
              <div class="main_frontpage">
                <div class="main_frontpage_i">
                  <?php if($this->countModules('left')) {?>
                  <div class="mega_left">
                    <div class="mega_left_i">
                      <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left" style="megarounded" />
                    </div>  
                  </div>
                  <?php }?>
                  <div class="front_page<?php echo $fright;?><?php echo $fleft;?>">
                    <div class="megaclass_1">
                      <div class="megaclass_2">
                        <div class="megaclass_3">
                          <div class="megaclass_4">
                            <div class="fp_megaclass_i">
                              <jdoc:include type="component" />
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <?php if($this->countModules('right')) {?>
                  <div class="mega_right">
                    <div class="mega_right_i">
                      <jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" style="megarounded" />
                    </div>  
                  </div>
                  <?php }?>
                </div>  
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mega_footer">
        <div class="footer_i">
          <div class="footer_w">
            <div class="footer_p">
              <!-- BOTTOM MODULES START HERE -->
                      <?php
                      $template = array ('botbox-1','botbox-2','botbox-3','botbox-4','botbox-5');
                      $bots = splitmodules ($this,$template,99);
                      if($bots) :
                      ?>
                      <?php if($this->countModules('botbox-1 + botbox-2 + botbox-3 + botbox-4 + botbox-5')) {?>
                      <div class="mega_bots" id="mega_bots">
                          <div class="mega_bots_i" id="mega_bots_i">
                            <?php if( $this->countModules('botbox-1')) {?>
                            <div class="botbox botbox1<?php echo $bots['botbox-1']['class']; ?>" style="width: <?php echo $bots['botbox-1']['width']; ?>;">
                                  <jdoc:include type="modules" name="botbox-1" style="megabox" />
                            </div>
                            <?php }?>
                            <?php if( $this->countModules('botbox-2')) {?>
                            <div class="botbox botbox2<?php echo $bots['botbox-2']['class']; ?>" style="width: <?php echo $bots['botbox-2']['width']; ?>;">
                                  <jdoc:include type="modules" name="botbox-2" style="megabox" />
                            </div>
                            <?php }?>
                            <?php if( $this->countModules('botbox-3')) {?>
                            <div class="botbox botbox3<?php echo $bots['botbox-3']['class']; ?>" style="width: <?php echo $bots['botbox-3']['width']; ?>;">
                                  <jdoc:include type="modules" name="botbox-3" style="megabox" />
                            </div>
                            <?php }?>
                            <?php if( $this->countModules('botbox-4')) {?>
                            <div class="botbox botbox4<?php echo $bots['botbox-4']['class']; ?>" style="width: <?php echo $bots['botbox-4']['width']; ?>;">
                                  <jdoc:include type="modules" name="botbox-4" style="megabox" />
                            </div>
                            <?php }?>
                            <?php if( $this->countModules('botbox-5')) {?>
                            <div class="botbox botbox5<?php echo $bots['botbox-5']['class']; ?>" style="width: <?php echo $bots['botbox-5']['width']; ?>;">
                                  <jdoc:include type="modules" name="botbox-5" style="megabox" />
                            </div>
                            <?php }?>
                          </div> 
                      </div>
                      <?php } endif;?>
                      <!-- END -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>  
      </div>
      <div class="bottom_menu_copyright">
        <div class="bottom_menu_copyright_i">
          <div class="bottom_menu">
            <div class="bottom_menu_i">
              <jdoc:include type="modules" name="bottom_menu" />
            </div>  
          </div>
          <div class="copyright">
            <div class="copyright_i">
              <jdoc:include type="modules" name="copyright" />
            </div>  
          </div>
        </div>  
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear: both;"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="debug" /></div>
  <!-- Yandex.Metrika counter -->
<script type="text/javascript">
(function (d, w, c) {
    (w[c] = w[c] || []).push(function() {
        try {
            w.yaCounter18543841 = new Ya.Metrika({id:18543841,
                    webvisor:true,
                    clickmap:true,
                    trackLinks:true,
                    accurateTrackBounce:true});
        } catch(e) { }
    });

    var n = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],
        s = d.createElement("script"),
        f = function () { n.parentNode.insertBefore(s, n); };
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.async = true;
    s.src = (d.location.protocol == "https:" ? "https:" : "http:") + "//mc.yandex.ru/metrika/watch.js";

    if (w.opera == "[object Opera]") {
        d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", f, false);
    } else { f(); }
})(document, window, "yandex_metrika_callbacks");
</script>
<noscript><div><img src="//mc.yandex.ru/watch/18543841" style="position:absolute; left:-9999px;" alt="" /></div></noscript>
<!-- /Yandex.Metrika counter -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вы бы ещё код фейсбука в 1 вопрос запихали, никто смотреть не будет, тем более код неотформатирован, и какая где строка, непонятно, а так, написано же: ищите ошибку на 72 строке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <div class="logobox_p">
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="logo" />
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if(!$this->countModules('logo')) { ?>
           <a href="<?php echo JURI::base()?>"  class="logo"></a>
        <?php } ?>
 </div>
```

Думаю, что тут лишняя закрывающая скобка - `<?php } ?>`, смотрите шаблон `header` через админку, доступ к cms у вас есть же?

Comment: Alex, правильно будет так <?php } ?. Правильно я понял?

Comment: Правильно будет убрать <?php } ?> в первом случае, у вас нет кода, который закрывает эта скобка

Comment: СПАСИБО ТЕБЕ ОГРОМНОЕ, НЕ ЗНАЯ ТВОЕГО ИМЕНИ.
Наш разработчик на косячил и слился. А сайт не работал.Жалко сайта было в поисковиках в ТОП  нашего регона

Comment: А такой вопрос: как на этом сайте главный баннер сменить?

Comment: @Евгений123, думаю, для баннеров там тоже должен быть модуль, а вообще почитайте документацию по cms, там не нужно особых программистских навыков, чтобы с ней работать полноценно.

Comment: Я нашол модуль, снять с публикации могу, а вот данных для изменений не найду.

Comment: На сайте разработчиков вашего сайта указаны и адрес и телефон. http://surgut-it.ru/